# wpa_supplicant removing all listed networks

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant

I'm using wpa_supplicant with connmand over Centos 7. When I start wpa_supplicant either as system service or manually, and with debug enabled, wpa_supplicant list all BSSID near my computer. Then, after a while, wpa_supplicant remove, unilaterally, all networks listed. How I can avoid this behaviour? I have compiled my own version of wpa_supplicant and this behaviour is also reproducible in it. This is my configuration file:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
```

The command line configured in system service is the following:

```
 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -ddt -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf $INTERFACES $DRIVERS $OTHER_ARGS
```

And when I start wpa_supplicant manually I exectue this:

./wpa_supplicant -u -ddt

Both have the same result, removing networks after a few minutes. Any idea?